# I can't use drawString in Java graphics

Tags: java, awt

I am making a Java game. I can draw images and other things, but drawString gives me an error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun.font.SunFontManager
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:82)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74)
at java.awt.Font.getFont2D(Font.java:491)
its longer...
```

This is the code:

```java
Font font = new Font("Arial",50,Font.PLAIN);
g2.setFont(font);
g2.drawString("Hello World!", 100, 100);
g2.dispose();
```

Comment: what is the `g2` variable? please describe all things that you are asking about. If `g2` is a canvas object then try with the `g2.drawText()` method.

Comment: g2 is Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; in paintComponent btw I can draw anything exept this

Comment: Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. 4 lines of code doesn't show us the context of how/where/when that code is used. So all you need is a JFrame with a JPanel showing how you override the paintComponent(...) method.

Comment: ok I will edit it

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Your tiny bit of code is wrong in two places.

```
Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 50);
g2.setFont(font);
g2.drawString("Hello World!", 100, 100);
// g2.dispose();
```

Your `Font` constructor takes a String, `Font` type, and int point size.

You don't dispose of a `paintComponent` `Graphics` object.

I can just imagine how many other errors and misconceptions there are in the rest of your code.

Comment: `"Arial"` will not be on many machines running MacOS. Better to use `Font.SANS_SERIF`.

Comment: this is not working :dislike:

Comment: @Java: You do need lots more code to create a complete Swing GUI with a drawable `JPanel`.

Comment: I have a lot I will upload it later